# EF. Select records from one table based on the properties of the records from second table that have an FK from the first

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have two tables.
BookTitles and BookAuthors. A BookTitle can contain multiple BookAuthors:

```
BookTitles:
- Book_Id
- BookName

BookAuthors:
- Author_Id
- AuthorName
- Book_Id
```

In the second table, the Book_Id is a foreign key. I'm using Entity Framework, database first.
Here's the model (created automatically) of the BookTitles table:

```
public partial class BookTitles
{
    public BookTitles()
    { this.BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthors>(); }

    public int Book_Id { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthors> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

The last property shows that the object of type BookTitles will contain the list of the BookAuthors  objects, retrieved from the second table.

The question: How do I retrieve the BookTitles records that will  contain, for example, the object of type BookAuthors that will have the BookAuthors.AuthorName == "AAA"?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
using (var db = new BooksContext())
{
    var books =
        db.BookTitles.Where(x => x.BookAuthors.Contains(new BookAuthors() {AuthorName = "AAA"})).ToList();
}
```

How do I query it using Lambda expression and how do i do this using LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Any` instead of `Contains`:

```
var books =
    db.BookTitles.Where(x => x.BookAuthors.Any(y => y.AuthorName == "AAA")).ToList();
```

or if `BookAuthor` contains navigation property to `BookTitles`, you should be able to do:

```
var books = 
    db.BookAuthors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AuthorName == "AAA").BookTitles.ToList();
```

Comment: The answer i was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
using (var db = new BooksContext())
{
    var books = from title in db.bookTitles
                from author in title.BookAuthors
                where author.AuthorName == "AAA"
                select title;             
}
```

Comment: That works excellent. Thank You. Any idea how to do it with Lambda?